# Can't learn the third Word of Power from Wulfgar

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm playing Skyrim on Xbox 360 with no DLC.

I have completed all the main quests until the Horn of Jurgen Windcaller and before I completed it I messed around with the game doing side quests and other things and I have logged a good 100+ hours. I'm level 39 and when I go to complete the quest and have Wulfgar teach me the third Word of Power but he won't do it.

I have tried talking to him and nothing, All the Greybeards are in the middle of the room except Arngeir which is waiting to be talked to about the Throat of the World quest so he is no help.

I am stuck so I made a new account (still have this glitches one) and did the main storyline everything worked on it. I don't want to start on my level 11 Orc because I have done too much stuff on my Nord. I have 6 Dragon Priest masks, level 100 smithing, almost all the Daedric Artifacts and a ton other things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it by speaking with Arngeir one more time.  He then comes inside with everyone, and you get the word.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I figured it out. I went to arngeir and spoke to him. Then he said the usual " go inside" but after that, the gate opened and he said "go ahead dragonborn, go to master boring" which if you recall is the whirlwind Sprint trial thing. You'll probably have to equip it though. Took me 40 mins to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Try shouting at him.   I try different things when the proper response doesn't happen....but remember to save first just in case what u try has the wrong outcome
Also i have noticed as the game advances you get the same word more than once so it is possible to just not bother with that third person and carry on to get that word another time

Comment: I don't know if shouting will help, but what you are saying about being able to learn the word elsewhere is completely incorrect.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem ; I fixed it by pickpocketing Wulfgar.